# install-gremlin-server.sh generates titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip which can not be unzipped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, titan, tinkerpop3

I am installing and Running the DynamoDB Storage Backend for Titan. Following the instructions given at [Installing and Running DynamoDB for Titan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.html#Tools.TitanDB.DownloadingAndRunning.title)

Fifth step asks me to install gremlin server using

```
src/test/resources/install-gremlin-server.sh
```

I did it but the generated file under server folder is titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip. Which can not be unzipped. It gives error

```
Archive:  titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip
End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
 a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
 unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip     or
    titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip.zip, and cannot find titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Moreover instruction 6 says to go to directory

```
cd server/dynamodb-titan100-storage-backend-1.0.0-hadoop1
```

No such directory is generated. Its only zip file generated which has different name and which is alno not getting unzipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the .sh file, there is a curl call which is not working from my (and maybe your) linux machine
The solution is to use wget instead of curl.

Replaced

`curl -s -O http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/${TITAN_VANILLA_SERVER_ZIP}`

with

`wget http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/${TITAN_VANILLA_SERVER_ZIP}`